# how to bind array json in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

i have an table with student info that should post to the server in array of json format
this is

```
<table id="temlTbl">
  <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Family</th>
     <th>Type</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>ali</td>
     <td>alavi</td>
     <td>one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>reza</td>
   <td>rezaiee</td>
   <td>two</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

this is jquery code to serialize data and post ajax method:

```
$(SaveTeacherBook).click(function () {  
        var students;
        var jsonobj = [];
        var item = {};
        var Type;
        for (var i = 1 ; i < temp.rows.length; i++) {
            item["ID"] = temp.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
            item["Name"] = temp.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
            item["Family"] = temp.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;
            switch (temp.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML) {
                case "One":
                    Type= "1";
                    break;
                case "Two":
                    Type= "2";
                    break;
                case "Three":
                    Type= "3";
                    break;
            }
            item["Type"] = Type;
            jsonobj.push(item);
        }
        students= JSON.stringify(jsonobj);

        $.post('@Url.Action("Student", "Home")', students);
    });
```

this is my action method :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewTeacherBook( IList<ViewModel.StudentViewModel> students)
{
    ...
}
```

and model:

```
class StudentViewModel
{
    public string ID {get; set;}
    public  string Name {get; set;}
    public string Family {get; set;}
    public string Type {get; set;}
}
```

this is json formatted data:

```
"[{"ID":"1","Name":"ali","Family":"alavi","Type":"1"},{"ID":"2","Name":"reza","Family":"rezaiee","Type":"2"}]"
```

i try to post json array object but don't bind in controller, can any one help me please?

Comment: Try setting a `contentType` of `application/json` for your ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to deserialize to the object in your action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewTeacherBook( string students)
{
    IList<ViewModel.StudentViewModel> = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IList<ViewModel.StudentViewModel>>(students);
}
```

Comment: You can, but you certainly don't have to. That's what model binders are for.

Comment: not sure if it works the way he is trying to achieve it

Comment: Do you get the json in your students string

Answer (score 0):

Your switch seems to be broken.  The property name that you're assigning to in the second and third case statements is day, but in the first you're assigning to Type (which looks right given your model).  I don't know for sure if this would cause the model binder to ignore your object and refuse to bind, but it's a good first step.

```js
switch (temp.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML) {
  case "One":
      Type= "1";
      break;
  case "Two":
      day = "2";
      break;
  case "Three":
      day = "3";
      break;
}
```

Comment: this is typing mistake in question!

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Are you not copying your code directly into the question?  If not, you could be missing the thing that is causing the problem.  Did you try changing your $.post to include the content type like JasonP suggested above?

Answer (score 0):

For the ajax request to be processed correctly by the model binder, the request needs to have the content-type specified as `application/json; charset=utf-8`

Try changing the `$.post...` line for the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Student", "Home")',
    data: students,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    success: onSaved,
    error: onError
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed my jquery code to :

```
$(SaveTeacherBook).click(function () {
...
 students= JSON.stringify({"students":jsonobj});
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Student", "Home")',
            type: "POST",
            data: students,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
```

and action method :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewTeacherBook( IList<ViewModel.StudentViewModel> students)
{
   ...
}
```

with this changes correctly binds